# Azure U-SQL Continous deployment using VSTS Powershell task

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm building CI/CD for my Azure Data lake Analytics - USQL code and facing below error while deploying my release using VSTS Power Shell task.

"Access from 'example-app1' is denied. Please grant the user with necessary roles on Azure portal. Trace: 03e7229d-e7ca-43d5-a7be-6e0a3a3b9317"

I have created Azure AAD following this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal and created a service End point. I also gave access to this AAD (example-app1) in my Azure Data lake analytics store path. Below is my ADLA - USQL code -

```
@searchlog =
EXTRACT UserId          int,
        Start           DateTime,
        Region          string,
        Query           string,
        Duration        int?,
        Urls            string,
        ClickedUrls     string
FROM "adl://adlacicd.azuredatalakestore.net/Samples/data/SearchLog.tsv"
USING Extractors.Tsv();

OUTPUT @searchlog   
TO "adl://adlacicd.azuredatalakestore.net/Samples/data/output/SearchLog-first-u-sql.csv"
USING Outputters.Csv();
```

any help in resolving this issue would be great.

Comment: I am not seeing any error related information in your question?

Comment: Sorry Peter updated my question now..

Comment: What's the result if you try it with relative path https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-analytics/data-lake-analytics-monitor-and-troubleshoot-jobs-tutorial? On the other hand, provide the detail steps you gave access to AAD.

Comment: Thanks Starian. I changed my path in my script as below - /Samples/data/SearchLog.tsv instead of "adl://adlacicd.azuredatalakestore.net/Samples/data/SearchLog.tsv" and its successfully gettting deployed.

Comment: Great! I post an answer that you can [accept it as answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) (To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in).

Comment: Hello,                                                                                                             I have raised this question in a seperate thread, but not getting answers on this -                                                                                                   
                I'm planning to build Continous integration and Deployment for Azure Data factory using PowerShell. So all the build and release process which can be done using VSTS has to be done using Powershell. If anyone can share any links or powershell scripts it would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using relative path instead: `/Samples/data/SearchLog.tsv`.